# How to close sockets in C (GCC on Linux)

Tags: c, sockets

I'm completely new to C.
And am following this yt [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtXEMwSG5-8&t=1381s) on sockets. However he's using the `close(sock)` function. There's 2 problems:

- There's no variable called `sock`. The socket is called something else.
- I can't find the close function. The compiler is saying that the function doesn't exist

Can you please explain. This question might seem a little too dumb.
Here's the Client code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    // Create a socket
    int network_socket; 
    network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Address for the socket
    struct  sockaddr_in server_address;
    server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_address.sin_port = htons(9002);
    server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    int connection = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &server_address, sizeof(server_address));
    printf("%d\n", connection);

    char response[256];
    recv(network_socket, &response, sizeof(response), 0);

    printf("%s\n", response);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a tutorial is bad, then find another tutorial.

Comment: Right before the cut screen, you can see Eduanix actually correcting the `close` line: https://youtu.be/LtXEMwSG5-8?t=1406.

Answer (score 8):

> There's no variable called sock. The socket is called something else.

Yes, it's network_socket in your code. So you want `close(network_socket);`.

> I can't find the close function. The compiler is saying that the function doesn't exist

You need `#include <unistd.h>`, which is where close() is declared. (If you look at `man close` you'll see this at the top.)

Comment: Thanks! This answered all my questions. Still curious about what went wrong since the guy in the vid didn't include unistd.h. But that doesn't really matter because its working

Comment: @RushiSrinivas.K Obviously, another header must have been implicitly including `unistd.h`, which is why the tutorial's code didn't need to.  Don't rely on that.  If you need to use something from a particular header, then just include that header yourself. If it has already been included, that is OK (provided the header is using proper include guards, which 99% of the time will be the case)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the socket file descriptor as the argument for `close()`. Which, for your code, is `network_socket`. So, `close()` need to be called as `close(network_socket);`

Also, you need to use the `<unistd.h>` header for the `close()` function.

Comment: Yes. The whole problem was not inluding unistd.h. The guy in the video didn't so I was confused